# The php files that written in linux os get error 500 on server

Tags: php, linux, apache, xampp, visual-studio-code

I develop a site on localhost (xampp), codes written in vscode editor, every thing on localhost ok and works perfectly but when I run it on server get error 500!

It's interesting when I copy the codes from uploaded php file and paste them in online created file with some name ,codes works !!!
why ? and how to resolve it!
thanks

Comment: windows and \*nix, are two different animals. `File` and `file` for the latter matters, should this be the case.

Comment: Check the logs from php and apache. Something like cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: You can also enable error reporting in the php file, it can show some basics: 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: so, you came here with a question and we responded and I've one for you. Q: your local's windows right? you uploaded a file to a \*NIX server with `Filename.php` but you're trying to access it as `filename.PHP` or something similar; am I right on this? The question lacks important *detail*. So, what say ye? Or, do you want to wait till the question gets closed and also leaving *you* high and dry?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The local and server both linux and webserver is apache, all files are have this issue, file names are ok too.

Comment: we've nothing to work with; best I can offer as did someone else; check your logs.

Comment: @Cryptopat still get error 500

Comment: Try a basic php file with just a: echo "Hello world";  If fail, check your install, paths for php, directory write access, group, etc you MUST access the logs file..

Comment: @Cryptopat At all if file created online its work,But if create and write on local host than upload, Its not work! :|

Comment: Don't use localhost for ajax upload, the browser is blocking you, check also the browser console. You have many problems. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution , The problem is files permission, change file permissions from 777 to 644